# Cakephp 3 EventManager not working on server (it has no listeners on server but in local has)

Tags: php, events, server, local, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to listen to "afterSave" callback using `EventManager` like this:

```php
use Cake\Event\EventManager;

EventManager::instance()->on(
    'Model.afterSave', function ($event) {
        // do something    
    }
);
```

**The problem**: On local it works, and I can "do something" when a Model is saved, but on server it doesn't work.

What I found is that on local `EventManager` has listeners associated. As you can see:

```php
use Cake\Event\EventManager;

debug(EventManager::instance());

object(Cake\Event\EventManager) {

    '_listeners' => [
        'Controller.shutdown' => '3 listener(s)',
        'Controller.initialize' => '2 listener(s)',
        'Controller.startup' => '2 listener(s)',
        'Controller.beforeRender' => '2 listener(s)',
        'View.beforeRender' => '2 listener(s)',
        'View.afterRender' => '2 listener(s)',
        'View.beforeLayout' => '2 listener(s)',
        'View.afterLayout' => '2 listener(s)',
        'View.beforeRenderFile' => '1 listener(s)',
        'View.afterRenderFile' => '1 listener(s)',
        'Model.afterSave' => '1 listener(s)'
    ],
    '_isGlobal' => true,
    '_generalManager' => '(object) EventManager'
}
```

But on server `EventManager` has no listeners:

```php
use Cake\Event\EventManager;

debug(EventManager::instance());

object(Cake\Event\EventManager) {

    '_listeners' => [],
    '_isGlobal' => true,
    '_generalManager' => '(object) EventManager'
}
```

Why isn't working on server? Does it have anything related with the server configuration?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'd look into Composer for this to make sure the autoloader is working.